# Vector of pointers pointing to object, can't access object data fields. (expression must have pointer type)

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have created my own Vector and Array classes which I have tested and work fine. However, in the following code I am having problems accessing the methods in an AccountInfo class. 
_accounts is declared like this:

```
Vector<AccountInfo*> _accounts[200]; // store up to 200 accounts
```

Before, _accounts was only of type AccountInfo. After switching to a vector, every instance that uses _accounts has the error: Expression must have pointer type.

Here is my code:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& s, UserDB& A){
    // print users

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < A._size; i++){
        //print name
        s << A._accounts[i]->getName() << endl;
    }
    return s; // return the statement
}    
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------    --------------------
//Destructor of UserDB
UserDB::~UserDB(){

        for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++){
            delete[] _accounts[i]; // delete objects in _accounts
        }

    }

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// add a new user to _accounts
void UserDB::adduser(AccountInfo* newUser){ 

        _accounts[_size] = newUser;
        _size++; //increment _size.
        if (newUser->getUID() > 0){
            //print if UID has a value
            cout << newUser->getName() << " with " << newUser->getUID() << " is added." << endl;
        }
        else {
            newUser->setUID(_nextUid); //automatically set UID for user if empty
            cout << newUser->getName() << " with " << newUser->getUID() << " is added." << endl;
            _nextUid++;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to access the AccountInfo methods from the variable _accounts?

Comment: You have an array of `Vectors`. And what is `Vector` anyway?

Comment: Vector is essentially my own implementation of a normal vector class.

Comment: OK, you have an array of those. But you seem to treat the array as if it were a single Vector.

Comment: I believe you wanted something like: `Vector<AccountInfo*> _accounts(200);`. Note the brackets. Also delete operator for vector entry doesn't need to be vector delete...

Comment: I actually have a method that overloads the [] operator,

DataType& ArrayClass<DataType>::operator[] (int k)

Comment: That's quite irrelevant. Arrays don't have "methods".

Comment: This needs an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be answerable. Show the (relevant part) of `Vector` definition.

Comment: If you don't understand what `Vector<AccountInfo*> _accounts[200]` does, I would advise against reimplementing `std::vector`.  It seems... unwise.  If you do know what it does, I would still advise against reimplementing `std::vector`, but for different reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You defined an array of vectors with:

```
Vector<AccountInfo*> _accounts[200]; // store up to 200 accounts
```

This is not the same as declaring a single vector with a capcity of 200.  If you were using a standard vector then it would look like:

```
std::vector<AccountInfo*> _accounts(200); // store up to 200 accounts
```

Comment: I am not using a standard vector, I made my own that does the same as _accounts(200) with brackets

Comment: @user3474814 What is the code for you `operator []`?  Generally `[]` is used to get an element at an index and not to create an object with that many elements.

Comment: @user3474814 No, you did not. There is no way in the language to override what `SomeType someName[200];` does. It will *always* declare an array of 200 `SomeType` objects named `someName`. This is not application of the `[]` operator (which can be overloaded), this is a plain & simple array declaration.

Comment: You are right, sorry about that. My code does return an element at the index. 

` (DataType& ArrayClass<DataType>::operator[] (int k)
{
 if ((k < 0) || (k >= size())) throw ArrayBoundsException();
 return paObject[k];
}
`
I have tested my code and know that the vector creation process works fine. I ran sample code and the vectors (created this way) were always correct. My issue is simply reaching the AccountInfo class methods using the Vector<AccountInfo*> _accounts variable. Is this possible?

Comment: @user3474814 If the variable is `Vector<AccountInfo*> _accounts;`, then the code is `_accounts[7]->methodOfAccountInfo()`. However, if the type of the variable is `Vector<AccountInfo> _accounts[200];` (as your question shows), then it's `_accounts[2][7]->methodOfAccountInfo()`, because you have an *array* of `Vector` objects.